# Trouble with uploading certain files PHP

Tags: php, debugging, file-upload

I just got a dedicated server and I can't upload MP4, MPEG, or FLV files.

I'm debugging and am not even uploading right now.  I'm just doing this when the form / upload script is posted:

```
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['add_lesson_info'])) {

            echo $video_name = $_FILES['add_lesson_video']['name'];
            echo '<br />';
            echo $video_type = $_FILES['add_lesson_video']['type'];
            echo '<br />';
            echo $video_size = $_FILES['add_lesson_video']['size'];
            echo '<br />';
            echo $video_tmp_name = $_FILES['add_lesson_video']['tmp_name'];
            echo '<br />';
    ........
```

When I upload any jpg, jpeg, png, or gif if outputs the data.  But, if I try MP4, MPEG, or FLV it doesn't output any data.  Any reasons why? Thank you.

**Note:** this wasn't an issue on a shared server.  So, it could be some root setting I'm unaware of.

**Here's the php.ini**

```
register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = off

expose_php = Off
max_input_time = 10080
max_execution_time = 10080

;extension_dir = ./
upload_tmp_dir = ./tmp

;precision = 12

session.cache_expire = 10080
session.cookie_lifetime = 200000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 10080

memory_limit = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 192M
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with the max filesize allowed, since videos tend to be larger than images. I would check the `php.ini` for these settings.

Comment: *UPDATED.  I added my php.ini

Comment: Have you considered checking $_FILE[<fieldname>']['error']?

Comment: Have you looked at your logs?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 3):

Before you do any further manipulation of uploaded files you need to make sure there were no errors during the upload. That's the part where you have to check `$_FILES['field_name']['error']` where you'll find a corresponding code indicating what might have gone wrong.

[Here are the values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) which `$_FILES['field_name']['error']` returns. Anything other than `0` or `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` means there was a problem during the upload.